# ThinkPad Hybrid USB-C with USB-A Dock and slow monitor response

Tags: usb, thinkpad

I have ThinkPad T945 with Ubuntu 20 on it. I just bought the ThinkPad Hybrid USB-C with USB-A Dock. I installed the latest DisplayLink driver for Ubuntu. The monitor is on and Ubuntu system can detect it, but the response of the monitor is slow and you can see the mouse cursor glitching while moving on the monitor. I have Samsung 4K monitor. Anyone knows a fix for that?

Comment: Please see thread here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349541/displaylink-laggy-displayport-screens-in-ubuntu-20-04-2-tls-kde-plasma-ryzen-470/1403728#1403728