# Displaylink Laggy Displayport-screens in Ubuntu 20.04.2 TLS KDE Plasma Ryzen 4700u

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde, displaylink

When attaching my HP Probook 635 Aero G7 to a Displaylink HP USB-C/A Universal Dock G2 the attached monitors using Displayport are extremely laggy.
The Laptop-Screen and HDMI-Display are fine.

System Information:

- Kernel Version: Linux 5.8.0-59-generic
- Processor: 8 processors, 8 cores,  AMD Ryzen 7 4700U with Radeon Graphics
- Linux Version: Description:   Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

I have attempted to install the newest Displaylinkdriver but it did not help.

The Dock works fine on the same ubuntu version with a laptop that has an I7 Processor, only AMD runs into problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offhand, not sure if there's an answer to a similar question here yet, but this is something that's been broken since the release of 20.04 alas.  I'm not sure if it's fixed in the release of 20.10 or 21.04, as I haven't tested those or looked into this.

Fortunately, the folks at DisplayLink made available a workaround [noted in a pinned forum post](https://displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=67148).

I would suggest trying the link above, in case the instructions change, but since Stack Overflow prefers the answer include steps to avoid bit rot:

(Edit 1-2022: The link below is no longer available; did not find an alternate source; see the other Answer)

```
# Download the debian file from https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/file?d=310
sudo dpkg -i xserver-xorg-core_1.20.8-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

For the juicier details here's the issue at [gitlab for xorg/xserver](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/issues/1028).

But! There's one more step you want after you install that workaround package... you want to avoid installing the package from mainline, so you can do:

```
sudo apt-mark hold xserver-xorg-core
```

(you can undo this with `apt-mark unhold xserver-xorg-core`)

---

Less useful, but an additional 'workaround' is that this issue (for me) does not happen if there is a non-DisplayLink screen also attached to the machine (e.g. HDMI) at the same time.  Had the workaround debian package not been made available, I probably would have ended up adding a HDMI EDID-emulating dongle to my DisplayLink-only system, but fortunately did not have to do this.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the very detailled reply at first.
I have tried this fix already and several others aswell, also downgrading to kernel version 5.4 etc, with no success. Today, I showed up at work and magically nothing of the issue occurs anymore, the mouse is as perfectly moving as it could be. It mightve been a fix of those, possibly yours, which i tried in advance, but I cant tell for sure...

Comment: The link is gone, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

As Gertlex correctly pointed out, the problem is rooted in the xserver ([see this issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/issues/1028)). Fortunately, the problem has been solved and the solution been merged into the xserver 1.20 branch. The first release to contain those fixes is 1.20.12 ([see repo history](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/network/master?extended_sha1=0086535e)), which is not currently available before Ubuntu 21.10 ([see ubuntu's package repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/xserver-xorg-core)).

Hence, I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 21.10, which is supposed to contain the fix. I installed the driver with the [script](https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian) by AdnanHodzic, rebooted and the described issue is solved indeed.

Knowing that it worked on a fresh install, upgraded my Kubuntu 21.04 to 21.10. Issue is now also gone on this machine.

I can't say yet if any new issues came up that are not related to this one, as I just finsihed the upgrade. Shall issues occur within the next few days, I'll note them here.

Tl;dr: Described problem is solved on (K)Ubuntu 21.10.

---

Working system information:

- Intel onboard graphics
- Xserver 1.20.12
- Kernel 5.13.0-20-generic
- Desktop computer with the only display connected through DisplayLink dock

Answer (score 0):

I solved it without upgrading by using Wayland instead of X11. Wayland is actually awesome now and I haven't noticed any issues yet. Wayland is also the new default in 22.04, unless you are using an Nvidia GPU.

RIP Nvidia users :-(