# Display lag on external monitor with ThinkPad Dock

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi, thinkpad, dockstation

I have a **ThinkPad Hybrid USB-C with USB-A Dock** connected to a **ThinkPad T14** laptop with **Ubuntu 20.04** and a DELL external monitor. I had no display on my external screen until I installed the following driver: https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu. Since then, display is working (both in HDMI and DP) but **response time is very slow**. Any idea how to fix this?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Cross-post: https://superuser.com/q/1683634

Comment: Please see thread here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349541/displaylink-laggy-displayport-screens-in-ubuntu-20-04-2-tls-kde-plasma-ryzen-470/1403728#1403728